# Sorting an array by letters then numbers not working

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

**/ Begin Updates /**

**The below solutions will work if I target a single array of arrays but not the array of arrays of arrays.**

This is only a chunk of the associative array, each grouped piece will need to be sorted. See updated array.

I've tried the following and it doesn't hit the subarray it seems:

```
function natorder($a, $b){
  return strnatcmp( $a['name'], $b['name'] );
}
usort($array, 'natorder');
```

**/ End of Updates /**

Trying variations `usort`, `sort` and the following function:

```
function sortNames($a, $b){
 return $a['name'] - $b['name'];
}
```

I am unable to sort my array:

```
    [abc-abc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => abc-abc-34
                    [qty] => 4
                    [sub_qty] => 4
                    [area] => G11
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => abc-abc-45
                    [qty] => 145
                    [sub_qty] => 146
                    [area] => G11
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => abc-abc-67
                    [qty] => 215
                    [sub_qty] => 100, 
116
                    [area] => T, 
G12
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => abc-abc-56
                    [qty] => 0
                )

        )
    [def-def] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => def-def-34
                    [qty] => 4
                    [sub_qty] => 4
                    [area] => G11
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => def-def-45
                    [qty] => 145
                    [sub_qty] => 146
                    [area] => G11
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => def-def-56
                    [qty] => 0
                )

        )
```

To the following:

```
        [abc-abc] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => abc-abc-34
                        [qty] => 4
                        [sub_qty] => 4
                        [area] => G11
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => abc-abc-45
                        [qty] => 145
                        [sub_qty] => 146
                        [area] => G11
                    )

                [2] => Array
    (
                        [name] => abc-abc-56
                        [qty] => 0
                    )


                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => abc-abc-67
                        [qty] => 215
                        [sub_qty] => 100, 
    116
                        [area] => T, 
    G12
                    )

            )
[def-def] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => def-def-34
                        [qty] => 4
                        [sub_qty] => 4
                        [area] => G11
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => def-def-45
                        [qty] => 145
                        [sub_qty] => 146
                        [area] => G11
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => def-def-56
                        [qty] => 0
                    )

            )
```

Do I need to account for the additional keys not present in `abc-abc-56`? Is there an alternate tool or function I should be using?

The name will always have the format of 3 letters, a dash, followed by 3 letters but after that it varies with other characters and numbers. So it could be:

> abc-abc-1, abc-abc1, abc-abc.1, or abc-abc_1

but I'm most concerned with the first pattern being sorted correctly.

Your review is much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the `strnatcmp()` function.

Comment: `int` value of any `abc-abc-...` is 0. `0 - 0` still `0`.

Comment: @Barmar I worked it in like so:
`function nameSort($a, $b){
return strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}
$test = nameSort($array);
usort($test);`
 to no avail

Comment: `function sortNames($a, $b){    return strnatcmp ($a['name'],  $b['name']);} usort($array, "sortNames");print_r($array);`

Comment: @bardicwarrior You're not calling a sorting function. `strnatcmp()` has to be used in the comparison function of a sort.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I'm afraid this didn't work, it sorts the letters just fine but the numbers are still out of order

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [https://3v4l.org/MSGU8](https://3v4l.org/MSGU8)

Comment: @Thefourthbird it *does* work when I have the function run over my array after the initial step within my forloop. Thanks! If you want to answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a multi dimensional array, you could use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) in the callback function.

In the callback of usort use [strnatcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php).

For example:

```
$array = array_map(function($x){
    usort($x, function($a, $b){
        return strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
    });
    return $x;
}, $array);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PGnO7)

For the single array with multiple names you could use:

```
function sortNames($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

usort($array, "sortNames");
print_r($array);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/MSGU8)